# check if the file in server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload

I want to save file in folder exist at server, not at my website, because some security issues,

```
if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Attchment")))
        // to create directory if it dose not exist.
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Attachment"));
        }

        var fileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Attachment/" + string.Format("{0}.jpg", codeText));
```

is the previous code can create folder in server, or not? and can save at it? 
"Directory.Exist"... is check the file in all server folders or only in my application folders?

Comment: It can, if you have the appropriate permissions. What's your question? Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Directory.Exist... is check the file in server folder or only in my website folder?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. ASP.NET code runs on the server, and `Server.MapPath()` maps a path relative to your web application.

Comment: I want to save files in folder in server like " c://AttachmentFile' not the place where my web application code is save

Comment: Then don't use `Server.MapPath()`, but use an absolute path.

Comment: can you rewrite the code above use the absolute path please

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Attachment")`.